# Get json array from sub mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a sub query in mongoose need to get array out of sub query and attach to main json out put/ object.
my first query get user info which contains blocked_users array which is nothing but array of user id's.

i my second query we get profile details of blocker_users array and append to main user object in blocked_users.

```
    var userId = ObjectID(req.body.user_id);
    //Get user
    newUserModel.findById(userId, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            utils.getResponse(res, req.url, messages.failure, "");
        } else {
                var userInfo = {};
                var blcked_contacts;
                //get users details from blocked contacts userid's array
                newUserModel.find({'_id': {$in:user.blocked_contacts}}, function (err,blocked_users) {
                    if(blocked_users){
                        //blcked_contacts.push(blocked_users);
                        console.log(blocked_users);
                        return;
                    };
                    /*else{
                        blcked_contacts = [];
                    }*/
                });
                userInfo['blocked_contacts'].push(blocked_users);
                userInfo['user_id'] = user.id;

                userInfo['country_code'] = user.country_code;
                //userInfo['blocked_contacts'].push(blcked_contacts);
                //userInfo['blocked_contacts'] = user.blocked_contacts;

            var userData = Array();

        }
});
```

Comment: Remove unnecessary code please

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly removed :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you're looking for. But saw a problem in your code. You've assigned the blocked_users to the blocked_contacts field outside the find method.

Since these calls are asynchronous in nature, it might happen that the assignment takes place even before the documents are fetched from MongoDB. So you should write your assignment statements inside the find methods' callback, just the way Medet did.

Comment: yes siddharth you are correct but i dont know how to do it

Comment: var userId = new ObjectID(req.body.user_id);
//Get user, you might need to populate user.blocked_contacts field
newUserModel.findById(userId, function(err, user){
    if(err){
        utils.getResponse(res, req.url, messages.failure, "");
    } else {
            newUserModel.find({_id: {$in: user.blocked_contacts}}, function (err, blocked_users ){user.blocked_user_detaails = [];
user.blocked_user_detaails.concat(blocked_user);
})
    }
});

Comment: See if this helps. I'm on phone right now so can't format my comment properly.

Comment: no luck siddharth all i need to do is get out the values out of second query

Answer (score 0):

Noticed few mistakes in your code like trying to use **.push** on an object. You cant do

```
userInfo['blocked_contacts'].push(blocked_users); // incorrect as userInfo is an empty object and you dont have an array defined for userInfo['blocked_contacts']
```

You probably get cannot push into undefined error for this. So instead do

```
userInfo['blocked_contacts'] = blocked_users;
```

Also you have to do this inside the second find() as blocked_users is only available inside it. So your final query should be something like

```
var userId = ObjectID(req.body.user_id);
//Get user
newUserModel.findById(userId, function(err, user){
    if(err){
        utils.getResponse(res, req.url, messages.failure, "");
    } else {
        var userInfo = {};
        //get users details from blocked contacts userid's array
        newUserModel.find({'_id': {$in:user.blocked_contacts}}, function (err,blocked_users) {
            if(blocked_users){
                userInfo['user_id'] = user.id;
                userInfo['country_code'] = user.country_code;
                userInfo['blocked_contacts'] = blocked_users;     // assign blocked_users into userInfo
                console.log(userInfo)   // Your required object
            } else {
                userInfo['user_id'] = user.id;
                userInfo['country_code'] = user.country_code;
                userInfo['blocked_contacts'] = [];   // assign null array if no blocked users fould
            }
        });
        var userData = Array();
    }
});
```

The result of console.log should be an object like this

```
{
    user_id : "..id of searched user...",
    country_code : "..country code of searched user..",
    blocked_contacts : [<array containing detais of all blocked users>]      // null array if no users found
}
```